# Factoring an integer matrix into unimodular and upper triangular matrices

Tags: integer-lattices, matrix-equations

I'm stuck at the following problem. I've read this somewhere, but the author did not provide a proof, probably assuming that this is `clear'.
Let $A \in \mathbb{Z}^{n \times n}$. Then, there exist a unique $B \in \mathbb{Z}^{n \times n}$ and a unique $U \in \mathbb{Z}^{n \times n}$ such that

- $\det B=1$
- U is upper triangular, with $0 \leq u_{ij}<u_{jj}$ if $i<j$. In other words, $U$ has non-negative elements and the largest being the ones on the diagonal.
- $ A = BU.$

I believe this problem is related to lattice reduction theory. If someone knows an argument why this is true or point out to a source where this is proved, I would be very grateful.

Comment: did you mean A = BU ?

Comment: Perhaps you mean to say $A = BU$ and think about what does the Gram-Schmidt orthoganalization process does to the column vectors of the matrix :-)

Comment: @Singhal: Gram-Schmidt will produce non-integer factors.

Comment: Ohh sorry @LutzL, I completely overlooked that entries have to be from $\Bbb{Z}$. At times like these, one wishes to have a down-vote for (one's own) comments!

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a similar strategy like in the euclidean algorithm. Take the first column of $A$. Select the smallest non-zero entry. Reduce all other rows by integer multiples of this row. Now select the new smallest non-zero entry and repeat, until all but one entry in the first column are zero. Exchange that row to the first place. Then continue for the submatrix under the $(2,2)$ element.

The row reductions and permutations are elementary integer unimodular matrices, so their product $B$ will also be integer and unimodular.

---

See also [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form)

Comment: Yes, thank you. Simple answer. The strategy only needs a small adjustment such that the condition $0 \leq u_{ij}<u_{jj}$ if $i<j$ is satisfied. But that's easy!