# Triangulation of integer matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, integers

I am working on a problem in combinatorics that concerns the homotopy type of the complement manifold of a toric arrangement. To generalize my result, I need to use a the following fact from linear algebra. However, I would like to ask more expert people in order to be sure I am right. Here is the question:

Let $M\in M_{d,d}(\mathbb{Z})$ be an integer matrix. Is it true that if $M$ has rank $d$, than it exists a $d\times d$ unimodular matrix $H$ such that $MH$ is triangular?

I guess this result is true because it seems a consequence of Gaussian elimination together with Euclidean division over the integers. Can you kindly confirm this? In that case, can you provide some reference? Thank you very much for any kind of helpful answers!

Comment: A very close question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687039/factoring-an-integer-matrix-into-unimodular-and-upper-triangular-matrices, where the answer basically describes what you suggested.

Comment: it is in Newman's book  Integral Matrices  page  15 Hermite Normal Form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

the next page is not shown in the preview.